# Oracle Apex calling external api in dynamic action Javascript code failing

Tags: oracle, api, oracle-apex

I have a dynamic action that is executing a javascript function.  The function is reached ok but as soon as I try to fetch the api data it fails with TypeError: Failed to fetch.

The API is set to allow all origins and is also working when called from console or any other method.

Is there something in APEX that is blocking my calls to the external api?  I have also added ACL just in case that was causing the issue but it still fails.

We are using Oracle 19 and Apex 22.1.

The call should return JSON and then I should be able to use the JSON to get the path to a report.  The call fails and does not reach the external server. When looking at the error I can also see

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'requestContent')

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the call to a jQuery ajax call with success callback and this is working.

I also found that the ACL was not set with the correct principal.  I used the schema but it was actually a user in apex that seemed to work.